# Do shallow copies share pointers? (C++)

Tags: c++, pointers, class, shallow-copy, default-copy-constructor

I know that if I do something like this:

```
class Obj
{
public:
    int* nine;
};

Obj Obj1; //Awesome name
int eight = 8;
Obj1.nine = &eight;
Obj Obj2 = Obj1; //Another Awesome name
```

then `Obj1`'s and `Obj2`'s `nine`s will point to the same `8`, but will they share the same pointer? I.e.:

```
int Necronine = 9;
Obj1.nine = &Necronine;
Obj2.nine == ???
```

will `Obj2`'s `nine` point to `Necronine`, or will it remain pointing at `8`?

Comment: Surely you mean `Obj1->nine`? I'd use some more descriptive names...nine as a variable name, being assigned 8? :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will Obj2's nine point to Necronine,
>   or will it remain pointing at 8?

It will remain pointing at 8. When this line is executed:
Obj Obj2 = Obj1; // every object has his own pointer
the `value(copy)` of `obj1.nine` is copied into `obj2.nine` and thats it.

Comment: Thanx.  The 8 was a typo, I'm fixing it now.

Comment: Hah. I assumed assigning a value of 8 to the variable nine was deliberate and intentionally amusing. Certainly, it was more amusing than assigning 9 to nine, but perhaps less so than assigning 5 to twoPlusTwo would have been :)